# LEN of value in the variable in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have a variable `@ColumnnName` in T-SQL **user defined function** that basically contains the column Name.

For example :

```
declare @ColumnnName= 'firstName'
```

which means I have a column with Name `firstName` in my table and have this column name stored in variable named `@ColumnnName`.

I have a query like this:

```
Insert into @Temp([Row], VarLength) select  Rowid, LEN(@ColumnnName) from Patients
 where 
/ 
*rest of code 
*/
```

In above query, `LEN(@ColumnnName)` will return `9` which is the length of firstName but not the value contained in the column firstName.

How do I get length of the value contained the column firstName and not the length of string firstName itself.

Edit:

Complete query is like this :

```
Insert into @Temp([Row], Counts, VarLength) select  Rowid, @counter, LEN(@ColumnnName) from Patients where 
(case when @ColumnnName = 'firstname' then firstname 
            when @ColumnnName = 'middlename' then middlename 
            when @ColumnnName = 'lastname' then lastname 
            when @ColumnnName = 'State' then [State] 
            when @ColumnnName = 'City' then City 
            when @ColumnnName = 'StreetName' then StreetName 
            when @ColumnnName = 'StreetType' then StreetType end) LIKE SUBSTRING(@parameterFromUser, 1, @counter) + '%'
```

Comment: I think you need dynamic SQL to achieve what you want. The problem is you cannot use dynamic SQL from within a UDF.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos: Exactly. Must be some alternative there?

Comment: Some ugly `CASE` construct checking for all possible values of `@ColumnnName` ?

Comment: Why does this have to be a function?

Comment: I don't have an sql server to test on, but I believe if you do LEN(<integer>) it will give you the size of the value of the column of integer's number. (that is 1 gives you column 1 etc.)   You can look up the column number  by joining to the schema tables.

Comment: @AaronBertrand : Because this function is to be called from a couple of other UDF's. So, I can not make it a stored procedure.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos: Could you please cite an example? I am at the point clueless how Case construct might help here.

Comment: @Hogan: Could not follow. elaborate,  please?

Comment: So you have a multi-statement table-valued function that needs to be called by other UDFs. Are they also multi-statement? I hope you don't think this is a good thing. Also @Hogan ordinal column number only works in places like `ORDER BY` - you can't do `LEN(ordinal)` and get the length of the value in the `nth` column.

Comment: Scalar and/or multi-statement UDFs are notoriously bad for performance. You are talking about nesting them which is magnitudes worse. Not only does the performance go out the window, it ends up creating a big bowl of spaghetti.

Comment: @AaronBertrand : No, those UDF's are inline TVF's. I guess I understand the performance issues with multiline TVF's . :) Thanks though. Above question is killing me :( . There has to be some way. A way for double reference , No?

Comment: Yes, you can try a CASE expression. Should be fun! Or you could use what most people use - a stored procedure instead of a chain of dependent UDFs. Sounds like a nightmare. Also the code in your question cannot possibly be from an inline TVF - you can't declare variables or use things like `@temp` in an inline TVF.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Oh, No. The code above is from Multiline TVF only. I meant that this multiline TVF will be called from inline TVF :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be a solution to your problem:

```
INSERT INTO @Temp([Row], VarLength) 
SELECT Rowid, CASE WHEN @ColumnnName = 'FirstName' THEN LEN(FirstName)
                   WHEN @ColumnnName = 'LastName' THEN LEN(LastName)
                   ... etc
              END AS len
FROM Patients
... etc
```

If you want to use the above `CASE` expression more than once in your query then you can wrap it inside a `CTE`:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT Rowid, CASE WHEN @ColumnnName = 'FirstName' THEN LEN(FirstName)
                      WHEN @ColumnnName = 'LastName' THEN LEN(LastName)
                      ... etc
                 END AS len
   FROM Patients
)
INSERT INTO @Temp([Row], VarLength)
SELECT Rowid, len
FROM CTE
```

Comment: Bestos : Thanks a ton :) Actually, I have these case statements in my where clause . Is there a way I can get this value right there to avoid having to write these case statements again in the same query ?

Comment: @Simran Yes, use a CTE or a subquery.

Comment: @AaronBertrand : Thank you so much for keeping with me. I have updated question with complete query. Could you please direct me syntactically? I am not trying to get spoonfed but I actually have no idea how to manipulate my query for this .

Answer (score -1):

You can use the EXECUTE command to run a dynamic SQL.
Say you have a string var, called @myvar with the name of a column. You can then build up a complete SQL statement (something like `'select '+@myvar+' from tableName;'`) and then use the EXECUTE command, like this simple example (from which you can build up your solution easily):

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE @temp NVARCHAR;
  SET @temp = 'getdate()';
  EXECUTE ('select '+@temp+';');
END;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can't use dynamic SQL. The query is inside of a UDF.

Comment: And does it have to be on an UDF? I mean, without any worth solution, could't you twist it a bit and take this portion out of the UDF?